# What would you call the husband of a widow?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I'm confused as I've been googling a bit and have seen "dead husband", "former husband", ... and even "ex-husband"...

So what would you use for ______ in polite conversation:

> The ______ of the woman in the big house down the street must've liked his gadgets a lot!

and

> I like working in your garden because your ______ had all the tools I need.

I'm looking for one (or maybe two?) words that politely *provide context*.

Comment: We would typically say "*the **late** husband of Mrs. X*...".

Comment: What's wrong with *husband*? In the first sentence, the use of *widow* makes it obvious that he's died; in the second sentence, it's just polite not to rub the widow's nose in his demise. And probably *has* should be *had*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Obviously.  Corrected question to clarify that I'm looking for what to call "the dead guy" to *give context.*  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I would still put *husband* in those spaces.

Comment: @DanBron Could you convert that to an answer as you're getting a lot of up-votes that are better spent on your rep then on a mere comment.

Comment: @Fabby Looks like my alert colleagues are already on top of it!

Comment: The bereaved husband of a widow.

Comment: @Blessed Geek: Um ... maybe you want to look up the definition of [bereaved](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bereaved). Are you talking about two ghosts?

Comment: Nothing. He won't hear you.

Comment: Some people say, "I brought you this suit jacket that Mrs. G wanted you to have.  They belonged to her husband, may he rest in peace."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My suggestions, having read the comments and agreeing with some.

> The [late] husband of the woman in the big house down the street must've liked his gadgets a lot!

You can only omit 'late' if she has not remarried.

If you were/are a friend of the woman/couple then it is more tactful to use his name.

> I like working in your garden because your James had all the tools I need.

If you are employed as a gardener then either you wouldn't know that her husband was deceased or she would explain something like, "These are my late husband's tools." In that case you simply use the same phrase that she used.

Comment: Googling for `+James +"Late husband"` gives me 1510 obituaries....  Might `James` be local language for `late husband`?  (I'm looking for a polite term that provides context)  Editing Question to clarify...

Comment: No - It's an ordinary name, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: It would help if you explained the relationships between the people involved. Are they relatives? Employees?

Comment: I suppose the majority has voted...  Accepted and upvoted!  (And to answer your question: it's just a theoretical question: I'm not a gardener, nor do I have a specific English-speaking lady on my mind...  **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

In addition to **"late husband"**, answered by chasly, I suggest **"deceased husband"** which sounds better than "departed" or "defunct" and is more "polite" than "dead" as you would like.

> [deceased](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deceased) - no longer living; dead.

Comment: *deceased* is, perhaps, better than *dead*, but it is pretty brusque and clinical. *Departed* is a euphemism for *dead* and is so because it alludes to the person "passing on" to a new stage of existence rather than ceasing to exist which may be of comfort to survivors.

Comment: +1 Framed as "her husband, now deceased," the wording _deceased_ sounds not at all abrupt or harsh to me. But one person's delicacy is another's coarseness, I guess.